# Get drag position without jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I'm implementing a drag and drop object inside html5 canvas and I was wondering how to get drag position. I know that one can use jQuery UI, but since my object would be draw in canvas hence there is no DOM structure to use, hence jQuery UI might not be useful.

Some code I tried to get mouse position for moving:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        $('#position').html(e.pageX + ', ' + e.pageY);
    });
});
```

It would be straight-forward if there is a special event for drop, but it seems that there isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

There is an event for drop but it's fired from the `droppable`, the `draggable` fires `stop` at the end of a drag operation so you may want to utilize that.

Comment: The question said "jQuery-UI might not be useful"!

Comment: @harsha For positioning the code that he has is perfectly fine and it's not using the jQuery UI event arguments of the draggable events. However he was asking for a drop event which is available.

Comment: Didn't get you. Can you give a code example? I'm using canvas as mentioned in the question, so can't initiate a `droppable` element for that (say a circle in the canvas).

Comment: @clwen If you are using a canvas then you cannot use a droppable, but you can utilize the stop event of the draggable.